# Split a string inside double quotes

Tags: java, split

I have this string:

```
"Dairy products","LAI","249","SMP","Skimmed milk powder, Intervention Quality - Lait écrémé en poudre","€/100 kg","EU","201906","204.05"
```

and I'm splitting it by comma

```
    data = line.split(",(?=([^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)");

    if (data.length == meta.size()) {
        products.add(new Prodotti(
            data[0],
            data[1],
            Integer.parseInt(data[2]),
            data[3],
            data[4],
            data[5],
            data[6],
            Integer.parseInt(data[7]),
            Double.parseDouble(data[8])
        ));
    } else {
        System.out.println(meta.get(data.length));
    }
```

This is what `data[4]` contains:

```
""Skimmed milk powder, Intervention Quality - Lait écrémé en poudre""
```

I don't know if this result is an error or is correct, also when I print it on JSON it appears like this:

```
"\"Skimmed milk powder, Intervention Quality - Lait écrémé en poudre\""
```

Comment: "_I don't know if this result is an error or is correct_". Whether it's correct or not depends on your requirements... what are they?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please clarify what result do you expect. Looks that the string is reall the 4-th (starting with index `0`) string parsed from your array.

Comment: I'm doing a rest API that displays in JSON format subset of a dataset based on users requests.

Answer (score 0):

If I were going to do this I would replace the `","` with `"#"` and the split on `#`.  It may not be elegant but it avoids some hassles.  Instead of `#` you could choose something else that is not within the quoted fields.

```java
      String str =
            "\"Dairy products\",\"LAI\",\"249\",\"SMP\",\"Skimmed milk powder, 
             Intervention Quality - Lait écrémé en poudre\",\"€/100 
             kg\",\"EU\",\"201906\",\"204.05\"";

      String[] substr = str.replaceAll("\",\"", "\"#\"").split("#");

      for (String s : substr) {
         System.out.println(s);
      }
   }
```

The above prints out as one might expect for normally quoted strings.  It may be that JSON did something special because of the character accents.